# Creating Contact Us XSLT in umbraco

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I am trying to use this code to select all of the pages for this website and if the url has contact in it. It would pull that specific url. I neeed to make it create a link with the url value that the for-each would pull.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '0'] [contains(@nodeName,'contact')]">        



           <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Umbraco the url is stored as url or niceurl (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/niceurl) - the node name is usually used to generate it - but its not the same thing.

Something like the following should work:

```
<xsl:variable name="siteRoot" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@level = 1]" />
<xsl:variable name="urlString" select="contact" />

<xsl:for-each select="$siteRoot//*[@isDoc][not(umbracoNaviHide = 1)][contains(umbraco.library:NiceUrl($currentPage/../@id), $urlString)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: That did bring back all the urls of everypage on the site not the page with contact in the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <xsl:variable name="siteRoot" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@level = 1]" />
<xsl:for-each select="$siteRoot">

  <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="translate(@nodeName,'.','')"/>_contact.aspx
    </xsl:attribute>
    Contact Us
</xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I just took the main pages name and added the _contact to it instead.